# Is there any canon between Season 1 of "Andor" and "Rogue One"?

Tags: star-wars, andor

Just finished season 1 of *Andor*. Absolutely loved it and want to know if there are any books or media that tells what will happen to Cassian between now and *Rogue One*.

Comment: Season 1 ends on 23 Nov 2022.  12 eps in total.

Comment: Given that there's already been a second season confirmed, for which any other version of the story would be either non-canon or a massive spoiler, I think it's safe to assume the answer is "not yet". That puts it firmly into the "future works" category, which I believe is considered off-topic here.

Comment: Technically yes - https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One_-_Cassian_%26_K-2SO_Special_1 - but agreed that this seems mainly a future works question.

Comment: This seems perfectly on-topic to me. There's at least one (and possibly more) canon works that deal with Andor's antics prior to Rogue One

Comment: @Valorum - would this not be considered a list/recommendation question?

Comment: @fez - Limited lists are fine. There can't possibly be more than a couple of examples. Now, if OP had said stories containing Luke between ESB and TFA, that would be unsustainable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far there are relatively few non-*Andor* appearances of Cassian Andor in material taking place before Rogue One.

### Cassian & K-2SO Special (2—0 BBY)

[image: Comic panels from Cassian & K-2SO Special, showing Cassian reprogramming K-2SO]

[*Rogue One - Cassian & K-2SO Special 1*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One_-_Cassian_%26_K-2SO_Special_1) is a standalone comic issue taking place between 2 and 0 BBY, and shows how Cassian and K-2SO met. It came out in August 2017 and takes place after the founding of the Rebel Alliance, which happened in 2 BBY.

### Secrets of the Empire (2—0 BBY)

[image: Screenshot of Cassian Andor in the Secrets of the Empire briefing]

[*Secrets of the Empire*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Secrets_of_the_Empire) is a "VR experience" formerly available at [The Void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Void_(virtual_reality)) locations. The players are given a mission by Cassian to infiltrate Darth Vader's castle on Mustafar. Cassian [introduces himself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4nk5jV9UmY) as "Captain Cassian Andor of Rebel Intelligence", indicating that it takes place after the founding of the Rebel Alliance in 2 BBY. It came out in December 2017.

### The Mighty Chewbacca in the Forest of Fear! (0 BBY)

Cassian also appears in the junior novel [*The Mighty Chewbacca in the Forest of Fear!*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mighty_Chewbacca_in_the_Forest_of_Fear!) I haven't read this one, but Google Books substantiates Wookieepedia's claim that Cassian makes an appearance:

> "Captain Andor, why is it important?"
>
> "That's classified information, and these are the Emperor's errand boys," said Cassian. "I think I'll keep that to myself."
>
> <sub>Source: [Google Books preview of The Mighty Chewbacca in the Forest of Fear!](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Star_Wars_The_Mighty_Chewbacca_in_the_Fo/CGJMDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=andor)</sub>